# How can I store text value of element in a variable in karate?

Tags: karate

I am trying to get the text value of element and storing it in a variable.

```
* configure driver = {type:'chrome'}
* driver 'https://www.webpagetest.org/'
* def orgName1 = text("//*[@id='header']/h1/a")
* def orgName2 = script("//*[@id='header']/h1/a",'_.textContent')
* print orgName1 
* print orgName1
```

Both of this is not working for me.

```
* match text("//*[@id='header']/h1/a") == "WebPageTest"
```

works fine

Comment: I think you should use some other framework. or improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @PeterThomas Can you please now look into it?

Answer (score 1):

Please learn how to use css selectors, that is way much better than that XPath complexity:

```
* def orgName1 = text('#header a')
```

If you really insist on XPath:

```
* def temp2 = text("//*[@id='header']//a")
```

By the way even this works for me:

```
* def temp3 = text("//*[@id='header']/h1/a")
```

So I have no idea what's missing on your side. I keep asking you to follow this process, but I guess that will never happen: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue